Flutter Android SDK 34 - Namespace not specified
I am trying to update my Flutter application to compile using Android 14 (API 34). When I try to sync my project through "Sync Project with Gradle File" in Android Studio (Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1), I get an error:
Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

android {
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
}

If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant;

But I already set namespace on my app module build.gradle
I already tried Invalidating Cache and restart with android studio and also tried to delete cache of gradle without success.
My Flutter doctor:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-IT)
    • Flutter version 3.7.12 on channel stable at /Users/username/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4d9e56e694 (1 year, 4 months ago), 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
    • Engine revision 1a65d409c7
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.89

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

This is my android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


This is my android/app/build.gradle:
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace 'com.myapp.app'
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        resourceConfigurations += ['en', 'it']
    }

    flavorDimensions "flavor"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            dimension "flavor"
            getIsDefault().set(true)
            manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel:"Joivy DEV"]
        }
        staging {
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            dimension "flavor"
            manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel:"Joivy Staging"]
        }
        prod {
            dimension "flavor"
            manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel:"Joivy"]
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias="MyApp"
            keyPassword="br7Tuphetr\$f"
        //   storeFile file(System.getenv("HOME") + "/Desktop/DV_AppMobile/myapp_prod.keystore")
        storeFile file("myapp_prod.keystore")
            storePassword="br7Tuphetr\$f"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
            classpath 'com.dipien:bye-bye-jetifier:1.2.1'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/com.android.tools/proguard/coroutines.pro']
        }
    }
    lint {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
}

and this is the android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:
#Thu Jul 13 11:44:22 CEST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME



This question is similar to: Android getting error: Namespace not specified. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
